# Junction Object to create many to many relationship between Tasks and Accounts?

Tags: reporting, activities, architecture, junction-object

I need to create a many to many relationship between Tasks and Accounts. The goal here is to relate many Accounts to a single Task - and also be able to report on this cleanly - ex: "User(assignedTo) met with Contact(WhoId) and discussed Account1, Account2, Account3 and Account4."

I understand the Activities object cannot be related to via lookup or master detail relationship, so instead as a workaround would I be able to use the Contact object? So, Contact being the parent and Account being the child on my Junction object?

Am I thinking about this approach correctly and would it still allow for me to use standard reporting with the example I mentioned above?

Please let me know if I can provide any more information, Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question seeks to relate a task/event to ONE Contact and MANY Accounts... and this is currently not possible.

Many Contacts (and, by extension, each of their Accounts) is possible, but to relate it to one Contact and to many non-Contact objects is not available.

Comment: While Tasks can be related to many Contacts (via the feature called "ManyWho" - which puts a junction object between Contacts and Tasks) they are NOT related via many WhatIDs in the same way. The Tasks will roll up to the Account view through the Contacts, but it is not related M:M to "what"s.

Answer (score -2):

Tasks or "Assignments" already has a many to many relationship with Accounts/contacts by specifying either the WhatID or the WhoID. Using multiple WhatIDs or WhoIDs creates the relationships you're looking for. The WhatID's would be for multiple AccountID's and WhoID's would be for multiple ContactID's.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am actually looking for a many to many between Tasks/Accounts. So example being looking at 1 Task record I want to be able to relate it to multiple Accounts. Instead of having to clone the Task many times - that is why I thought a Junction object might be appropriate for the situation.

Comment: This is NOT TRUE. While Tasks can be related to many Contacts (via the feature called "ManyWho" - which puts a junction object between Contacts and Tasks) they are NOT related via many WhatIDs in the same way. The Tasks will roll up to the Account view through the Contacts, but it is not related M:M to "what"s.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to point out my error with respect to the WhatID and post a brief answer to the OP based on mine and these comments. Were I to now delete this post due to "peer pressure" downvotes, the answer you've posted would not be nearly as complete as it could have been.

Comment: Please delete your "answer." I have posted a proper response to the question.